# Jira Big Picture JQL - How to list issues below a given issue without using specific links between issues

Tags: jira, jql

We're using Jira Big Picture to model a simple project plan. The graphical view is similar to the scheme below.

How do I write a JQL query to get a resulting list of all level 4 issues **F-H** by specifying the level 3 issue **E**?
In pseudo code it would be something like:

**project = XYZ and issue is childOf(E)**

But I could not find any solution to this.

```
v A [Level 1]
├-o B [Level 2 (just 1 entry)]
├-> C [Level 2 (collapsed)]
├-v D [Level 2 (expanded)]
│ ├-v E [Level 3 (expanded)]
│ │ ├-o F [Level 4]
│ │ ├-o G [Level 4]
│ │ └-o H [Level 4]
```

We do not maintain the links explicitly. But Jira must somewhere store the links between the issues. Otherwise it would not be able to generate the graphical tree view. But where? And is it usable in JQL?

Thanks for any hints :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Enhanced JQL (Jira Server or Jira DC)

```
issue in allBoxDescendantTasks(BOX-ID, TASK-KEY,X)
```

https://appfire.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DLP/pages/297767103/Enhanced+JQL

- PROG-1 - the box id
- ABC-4 - the key of A task

Your case:

```
issue in allBoxDescendantTasks(PROG-1, ABC-4, 3) 
  AND NOT issue in allBoxDescendantTasks(PROG-1, ABC-4, 2)
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! It is exactly I was looking for :-)
The only thing I struggled some minutes was the “BOX-ID”. I had no clue where to get it from, until I coincidentally saw in the URL the word “box” (“…/#/box/<our-box-id>/g”).

Comment: This can now be implemented for the Cloud as well [BP-9023](https://appfire.atlassian.net/browse/BP-9023)